# Functions are not valide as a React child React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I have the next error "**Functions are not valid as a React child React Native**", I am trying to show a drawer when I press an image in my header (create with `react-navigation-stack` library), then I am using `react-navigation-drawer`. Everything is OK until now, the problem start when I try to pass the variable navigation to my function to use in `createStackNavigator`, I don't know what is the correct way to pass this variable.

[I want some like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtOyD.jpg)

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import {TouchableOpacity, Image} from "react-native";
    import {createDrawerNavigator} from "react-navigation-drawer";
    import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

    //IMPORT SCENES
    import HomeScreen from "../scenes/Home";
    import UpdateProfileScreen from "../scenes/home/UpdateProfile";

    const HomeStack = ({navigation}) => createStackNavigator(
        {
                Home: HomeScreen,
                UpdateProfile: UpdateProfileScreen,
            },
            {
                initialRouteName: 'Home',
                defaultNavigationOptions: ({
                    headerLeft: () =>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', margin: 16}}
                                          onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
                            <Image style={{width: 24, height: 24}} source={require('../images/open-menu.png')}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                })
            }
        )

    export default DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
        HomeStack
    })
```

How can I fix this, I'm new to React Native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `HomeStack` with this :

```js
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  UpdateProfile: {
    screen: UpdateProfileScreen
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({ // change here
    headerLeft: () =>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', margin: 16 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
        <Image style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} source={require('../images/open-menu.png')} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
  })
})
```

And

Replace your `DrawerNavigator` with this :

```js
export default DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    HomeStack: {
      screen: HomeStack
    }
})
```

Comment: well, this fix the error, but now i have the problem with the variable navigation, is not declarade, then i have the error "Can't find variable navigation"

Comment: @EdgarCamberos You can access navigation from `defaultNavigationOptions` also. I updated the answer. Please check.